# Populate list from array

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

if i have an array. can i populate a generic list from that array:

```
Foo[] fooList . . . (assume populated array)

// This doesn't seem to work
List<Foo> newList = new List<Foo>(fooList);
```

Comment: That code definitely works.  What is happening when you attempt it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could convert the array to a List:

```
string[] strings = { "hello", "world" };
IList<string> stringList = strings.ToList();
```

Comment: ToList() isn't even necessary since arrays already implement IList<T>. ;)

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for [List(t).AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) Method

Answer (score 6):

As @korki said, AddRange will work, but the code you've posted should work fine. For example, this compiles:

```
var i = new int[10];
var list = new List<int>(i);
```

Could you show us more of your code?